# How to call a Public Sub function of a window from another Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have A Wpf window with a Public Sub function(Window1). I need to execute that function from another window. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Window2_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Window1.Loaded

Dim Window1 As New Window 1
Window1.function()

End Sub
```

I'm very new to wpf. Please help me on this.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make the function public in Window1.

```
Class Window1 
    Public Sub MyPublicFunction()
        'DoSomething'
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any specific reason why it has to be in Windows1 and be an instance function? You could do this as a static public function in the App class so every part of your project gets access to it.